# Can't resolve IP address to hostname

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I was originally running a server from the Java main method for an Android application but was forced to instead run it through a Android main activity due to Android Studio. Upon trying to run it from the main activity I have run into issues with it binding to the specified port. When I try to connect with my Client (which I know works fine) it returns connection refused errors that indicate to me that my server isn't actually listening in on the specified port. Here is my server and main activity. I believe there must be some small issue with my syntax in setting it all up.

```
public class Server extends Thread {
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
final Reactor reactor = new Reactor();
int port;
boolean running;

Server(int p) throws  IOException {
    running = true;
    port = p;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (running == true) {

        try {

            System.out.println("Connecting");
            System.out.println("Server running on port: " + port);

            Socket listener = serverSocket.accept();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my mainActivity that is meant to just start the Server thread that listens on the specified port

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Server server = null;
    try {
        server = new Server(4600);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    server.start();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is the stack trace from the client side

```
  02-14 17:42:56.109    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕    j       java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "172.17.201.280": No address associated with hostname
 02-14 17:42:56.109    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at     java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
 02-14 17:42:56.117    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
 02-14 17:42:56.117    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-14 17:42:56.117    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:108)
 02-14 17:42:56.117    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
 02-14 17:42:56.127    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
  02-14 17:42:56.127    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at edu.carleton.l8client.Client.run(Client.java:99)
  02-14 17:42:56.127    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
  02-14 17:42:56.137    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
  02-14 17:42:56.137    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
   02-14 17:42:56.147    1314-1364/edu.carleton.l8client W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
```

Comment: Can you provide the StackTrace which is thrown.

Comment: Are you running the server and client both in the same network? And is the IP correct? The port is not the problem.

Comment: Yeah the port is correct and so is the IP address. I have ran it many times and am aware that is usually when this error pops up

Comment: You set the right permissions to the Android App? 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: I don't have that second permission you included so I will add that . Also do I want to user the IP address from my computer or the virtual device for the server?

Comment: You run the server on a computer and the app on a emulator? Just use localhost.

Comment: ok I am doing all that the same error still persists

Comment: Whee is the evidence about the server not binding to a port? Where is the connection refusal? Why do you post the server code when the error is coming from the client code? What is this question actually about?

Comment: The error is client only. Your problem is not on the server side. It looks more like you have a network setup issue.

Comment: I have checked the client on a server that runs from a main() method and it works fine... It just won't connect to this server that runs from the main activity. It returns this exception because there seems to be nothing to connect to

Comment: Your stack trace shows an `UnknownHostException`. Not a `BindException`, or a `ConnectException`.

Answer (score 2):

172.17.201.280 is not a valid IP Address so it interprets it as a Hostname.

Try something in the Range of 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255

(280 is > 255)

Comment: The IP address is fine. I have tested my client on a server run from main() and it works fine.. It is just the above server run from the main activity does not work

Comment: Quote: Unable to resolve host "172.17.201.280" That is NOT a valid IP address. That's why he says unable to resolve host. Now you have to find out where it comes from.